# visibility CSS not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I've got some styling on an a tag so that some text appears only when rolling over. It only seems to be broken in IE8. It's for the three dots just below the homepage slider.

The link:

http://www.escape2ski.com

The HTML:

```
<div id="threeDots">

   <div class="dot first">
     <p class="dotButton"><a class="btn1" href="http://escape2ski.com/mountain-locations/"><span>Explore</span></a></p>
  <h2>Take a Tour</h2>
  <p>Check out our in-depth listings to<br>see what we have to offer.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="dot second">
  <p class="dotButton"><a class="btn2" href="http://escape2ski.com/ask-escape2ski/"><span>Ask Us</span></a></p>
  <h2>Let Us Help</h2>
  <p>Got specific questions? Wonder if<br>your itinerary will really work?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="dot third">
  <p class="dotButton"><a class="btn3" href="http://escape2ski.com/plans/membership-options/"><span>Join</span></a></p>
  <h2>Membership</h2>
  <p>Get an all-access pass to every<br>info&#8209;packed listing on our site.</p>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.dotButton a span {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Works in other browsers, on mobile... but not IE8.

Any idea why?

Thanks!
Adam

```
.dotButton a:hover span {
visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: **FIRST**, fix [your broken HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fescape2ski.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), then work on whatever is left.  (IE hates invalid HTML).

Comment: Good call Sparky, it looks like there is an unclosed div that just might be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, and I do always forget to do this basic check, so apologies there. BUT, here's the thing. I broke apart the entire source HTML of the homepage, and that "wrapper" div flagged as unclosed? It IS closed. Absolutely. So, I'm baffled why it's erroneously marked unclosed, and unfortunately no closer to a solution. The other flagged areas were seemingly unrelated to the problem at hand...

Comment: I will try and eliminate all the other errors if I can, and then see if the trouble remains.